# Trouble with ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

Can you please help me? I have the same problem and I can't fix it

```
create table minimarketi (id number(6) constraint min_id_pk primary key
  , ime varchar2(40) not null
  , adresa varchar2(100)
  , grad varchar2(30)
  );

create table zahtjevi (id_minimarketa number(6)
  , rbr_zahtjeva number(6)
  , datum_izdavanja date
  , constraint zaht_pk primary key(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva)
  , constraint zaht_min_fk foreign key(id_minimarketa) references minimarketi(id)
  );

create table artikli (sifra number(6)
  , constraint art_sifra_pk primary key(sifra)
  , naziv varchar2(100) not null
  );

create table stavke_zahtjeva (id_minimarketa number(6)
  , rbr_zahtjeva number(6)
  , sifra_artikla number(6)
  , kolicina number(6) not null
  , constraint stavke_zahtjeva_pkl
       primary key(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva, sifra_artikla)
  , constraint stav_zaht_idrbr_fk
     foreign key(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva)
     references zahtjevi(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva)
  , constraint stav_art_fk 
     foreign key(sifra_artikla)
     references artikli(sifra)
  );

create table isporuke (rbr_isporuke number(6)
  , id_minimarketa number(6)
  , rbr_zahtjeva number(6)
  , datum izdavanja date
  , constraint isporuke_pk
      primary key(rbr_isporuke, id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva)
  , constraint ispo_zaht_fk
       foreign key(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva)
       references zahtjevi(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva)
  );
```

with this table `isporuke` I have a 907 problem?

Comment: Formatting your code goes a long way in helping resolve syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this with table `isporuke`. You are creating you have a space in the table of a column.

You have:

```
 datum izdavanja date,
```

But you should have:

```
 datum_izdavanja date,
```

So your script will be:

```
create table isporuke 
(
  rbr_isporuke number(6), 
  id_minimarketa number(6), 
  rbr_zahtjeva number(6), 
  datum_izdavanja date, 
  constraint isporuke_pk primary key(rbr_isporuke, id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva),
  constraint ispo_zaht_fk foreign key(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva) 
    references zahtjevi(id_minimarketa, rbr_zahtjeva)
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9032b)

I found this by adding each table individually to the script to make sure that it would compile.  By running each one separately, you can eliminate the code that is working and narrow down the error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to debug these problems.

First, try each statement one at a time.  Rather than trying all five CREATE TABLE statements, try the first one and see if it passes.  Then try the next.  You're narrowing it down to a certain statement.

Now you know which statement has a missing parenthesis.  Look at the opening parenthesis, and see where its counterpart closing parenthesis is.  Does it match what you think it is?  Keep going through all the opening parens and find its matching paren.  Eventually you will find the opening paren that doesn't have its matching closing paren.

Also, clean up your code so that it's not all on one line.  It's much harder to debug this:

```
create table minimarketi (id number(6) constraint min_id_pk primary key, ime varchar2(40) not null, adresa varchar2(100), grad varchar2(30));
```

but when it's formatted like so it's much easier to see:

```
create table minimarketi (
    id number(6) constraint min_id_pk primary key,
    ime varchar2(40) not null,
    adresa varchar2(100),
    grad varchar2(30)
);
```